# python ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import a package

Tags: python, module, package, sys.path

I have two folders on my desktop, one called 'testpackage' and another called 'testplay'. 'testpackage' contains an **init**.py and another file named 'numberstuff.py' (a class with two methods). 'testplay' contains 'play_01.py', a simple script to just check I can add a package to the sys.path without physically adding it into the library in sys.path, I thought I could do this by sys.path.append(path\to\file) on python3 on windows.

testplays 'play_01.py' code:

```
import sys
for i in sys.path:
    print(i,'\n')

sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\priper\\Desktop\\testpackage')
from testpackage import numberstuff


a = numberstuff.maffs()
print(a.sqrtx(3))
```

console return:

```
   C:\Users\priper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.zip 
C:\Users\priper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs 
C:\Users\priper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib 
C:\Users\priper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37 
C:\Users\priper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages 
C:\Users\priper\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ 
C:\Users\priper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\win32 
C:\Users\priper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib 
C:\Users\priper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin 
C:\Users\priper\Desktop\sdnplay 
C:\Users\priper\Desktop\mypackage 
sdnplay.py 
sdnplay.py 
sdnplay.py 
sdnplay 
sdnplay 
C:\Users\priper\Desktop\sdnplay 
C:\Users\priper\Desktop\sdnplay 
C:\Users\priper\Desktop\sdnplay 
C:\Users\priper\Desktop\sdnplay 
C:\Users\priper\Desktop\testplay 
C:\Users\priper\Desktop\testpackage 
C:\Users\priper\Desktop\testpackage
```

Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testpackage'

File"C\Users\priper\Desktop\testplay\play_01.py", line 6, in <module> from testpackage import numberstuff
```

I can see testpackage is there in the sys.path, I just cannot figure out why it is being treated as a module and why I can't import it>

expected output is '9'.

Comment: Try `from testpackage.numberstuff import *` instead of `from testpackage import numberstuff`

Comment: Hi Anwarvic, same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can imagine is that you have called the folder "testpackage" but the file you are trying to import has another name. But since you are trying to import a file named "testpackage" you get the exception.

I have tried to reconstruct your problem but wasn't able to.

my folder/file structur looks as follows:

```
/full/path/to/the/parent/folder:
    - main.py
    - theFolder/
        - IAMATEST.py
```

The **main.py**

```py
import sys

sys.path.append('/full/path/to/the/parent/folder/theFolder')

from IAMATEST import IAMATESTClass

IAMATESTClass.calla()
```

The **IAMTEST.py**

```py
class IAMATESTClass:
    @staticmethod
    def calla():
        print("GOT CALLED")
```

and when executing the **main.py** I get the output "GOT CALLED".

Good luck!